# Pytorch issue when allocating second A100 GPU "RuntimeError device >= 0 && device < num_gpus INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED"

Tags: python, pytorch, multi-gpu, large-language-model

I have access to a cluster with a bunch of A100 GPUs. When I allocate one GPU, the following simple code executes properly:

```py
import torch

print(f"Pytorch version: {torch.__version__}")
print(f"Is CUDA available?: {torch.cuda.is_available()}")
print(f"Number of CUDA devices: {torch.cuda.device_count()}")
device = torch.device('cuda')
print(f"A torch tensor: {torch.rand(5).to(device)}")
```

Output:

```
Pytorch version: 2.0.1+cu117
Is CUDA available?: True
Number of CUDA devices: 1
A torch tensor: tensor([0.3157, 0.8026, 0.1049, 0.2574, 0.2896], device='cuda:0')
```

When for exactly he same code I allocate two A100 GPUs, I get as output:

```
Pytorch version: 2.0.1+cu117
Is CUDA available?: True
Number of CUDA devices: 2

RuntimeError device >= 0 && device < num_gpus INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED
```

I saw somewhere that a solution would be the environment variable to change to `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1` or to compile it as `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python script.py`, but does not work for me. Any ideas how to proceed for here? I need the second GPU to proceed with a LLM that does not fit in one GPU.

Comment: `torch.device('cuda')` is probably wrong.  You likely need to specify an index when there are multiple devices available. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html#torch-device